# What is the purpose of using Field(...) as a default value in pydantic schemas

Tags: python, pydantic

I've read some parts of the Pydantic library and done some tests but I can't figure out what is the added benefit of using `Field(...)` (with no extra options) in a schema definition instead of simply not adding a default value.

So what is added here:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int = Field(...)
```

that is not here:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int
```

**Is there any special behaviour that I'm missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are basically the same, the reason you might want to do this is so you can supply other settings to the field via kwargs to `Field()`.

If you have no other settings for the field, using `Field()` is unnecessary.